# Count instances within a certain timeframe

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Good afternoon,

I have a set of data that has an ID and a create timestamp. If the timestamps are within 15 minutes of each other for each ID, it is considered 1 "occurrence". There can be more than 1 occurrence per ID.  As soon as the timestamp is > 15 min from the first for the id, I need it to be considered as a new occurrence. Then it starts over. From the new occurrence, look at the next record and if it is 15 minutes from the timestamp consider it a single occurrence, so on and so forth.

I hope that makes sense.

example below.

```
ID              TIMESTAMP           OCCURRENCE
123abc  7/19/2022 16:32                  1
123abc  7/19/2022 16:35 
123abc  7/19/2022 16:37 
123abc  7/19/2022 16:39 
123abc  7/19/2022 17:32                  1
123abc  7/19/2022 17:40 
123abc  7/19/2022 17:42 
123abc  7/20/2022 19:35                  1
123abc  7/21/2022 16:35                  1
123abc  7/22/2022 23:42                  1
123abc  7/22/2022 23:44 
123abc  7/22/2022 23:45 
123abc  7/22/2022 23:58                  1
456deg  7/19/2022 16:42                  1
456deg  7/19/2022 16:44 
456deg  7/19/2022 17:15                  1
456deg  7/19/2022 17:18
```

I'm not sure where to start. I'm intermediate in sas but not a code macro'er. Could someone help me out or point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is sorted by ID and TIMESTAMP then you can quickly number the occurrences by just using the DIF() function to calculate the difference in seconds between the two datetime values.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id timestamp;
  gap = dif(timestamp);
  format gap time12.;
  if first.id then occurrence=1;
  else if gap > '00:15:00't then occurence+1;
run;
```

Post actual data as text (not photographs) to get tested code.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is making sense. However its doing an iterative count  (1,2,3,4 etc.) . I'd like to just show a 1 for every new occurrence. It never stops, it keeps adding a 1 for every instance regardless of ID. Also, the first instance shows a 0 and not a 1.  
                                       That way I can just sum by ID and show the number of occurrences, does that make sense? I've tried to update the post to reflect text and not an image.

Comment: I changed the line of 'if first.id then occurrence+1' to  'first.id then occurrence=1' and it seems to do mostly what I need. However the first record for each ID is still showing ./blank. Thoughts?

Comment: cancel that! I am good to go! Thank you Tom as always.

Comment: Your proposed structure will only identify the first record of an occurrence. The posted code should create a variable that can be use to find all of the observations in an occurrence.